# Selection Sort code is not working properly when the input is given Zero or negative numbers

Tags: java

When modification or changes does the below code requires to work properly for selection sort when the input are 0 or negative numbers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SelectionSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i,j,pos,swap=0,n;
        int[] array = new int[100];

        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        n = input.nextInt();

        for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++) {
            pos=i;

            for(j=i+1;j<n;j++) {
                if(array[pos]>array[j])

                pos = j;

                if(pos!=i) {
                    swap=array[i];

                    array[i]=array[pos];

                    array[pos]=swap;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int a=0;a<n;a++) {
            System.out.println(array[a]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Below is the actual input I have in the console box:                                            Enter the number of elements
5
6
0
1
-5
3
1
0
3
-5
6

Comment: Okay. What have you tried so far to fix the code? Which bit are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

First think about what selection sort does. We consider the array as a collection of two parts: sorted and unsorted. One index keeps track of how large the sorted part is (that is `i` in your code). At first, i is zero because nothing is sorted. The other index (that would be `j`) is used to find the smallest number in the unsorted part.

From the unsorted part, we select the first element and assume it's the smallest (so we set `pos = i`, as i is the size of the sorted part, which conveniently points to the first element of the unsorted part). To verify there is no smaller number (which there probably is), we iterate over the unsorted part (that would be the inner loop) and compare each number to what we currently believe is the smallest one. If we find a smaller number, we update our current knowledge of what is the index of the smallest number.

```
if(a[j]<a[pos]) pos = j;
```

When we reach the end of the loop (**after** checking the entire unsorted part), we want to move the smallest number from the unsorted part to the sorted part (if it's not already there, so if `i!=pos`). To do this, we move it to the front of the unsorted part (using a swap operation) and increment i, which then indicates the sorted part has grown.

Can you fix your code with these pointers?

Comment: Here's a tip: I copied your code and moved a part of it around, and this happened when i put in the following: 8(numbers): 1, 6, 0, -5, 9, 0, 7, 3 => -5, 0, 0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 9